# Use SignalR with barcode scanner

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, winforms, signalr

I have a legacy winforms application which is being used by a coffee shop vendor. We have integrated Barcode scanner as an activex component with the app and things are working as expected.

We have ran into a problem recently when the customer tried to use the barcode scanner for a webapplication while leaving the existing winforms application minimized. She was not able to use the barcode scanner as it was registered for the winforms app and only after closing the connections was she able to use with webapp.

To overcome this, Would like to know if we can use SignalR instead of ActiveX for using Barcode scanner with the application. So there would be central hub with 2 clients (Web app and winforms) and hub can decide which response to send to which subscriber. Any thoughts on this would be really helpful for us to proceed further on this.

Comment: Barcode scanners which which I've ever seen work like a keyboard. They send keys to the active window, regardless of being a web browser, notepade, my application or anything else. So if by closing your application and using 2 instance of notepad, each instance can receive keys when it's active, there could be some problem with your application.

Comment: I am not using the Barcode scanner as a mere input device. To give you a background - In Code, I check at which COM port it's connected to and then Initialize my ActiveX scanner object on the device on that COM port. So It means that my process - Winforms.exe is listening to the COM port and the web application project when tried to initialize the Barcode activeX object is thrown an exception saying Com Port is in use. So I would like to make this a hub and make all my subscribers connect to it and send responses as SignalR messages.

Comment: @Dinny If I were you I'd try to see if I can use it like a keyboard without listening to com port. If not possible, then I'd create an application/windows service which listen to the com port and after receiving data, send keys to active window simply using `SendKeys`. This way the only connected app to the port is your application/service and all other applications will receive data in a way which they receive data from keyboard.

Comment: @Oliver - Even then I would hit the same road block if I use activeX. As said above my Connection Instance would be limited to one client again and would end up with the same situation.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Not sure how efficient would that solution be but nevertheless let me give it a try. Thanks for suggesting a workaround.

Comment: @Dinny You're welcome. It's not very different from the hub which you were goring to create. Listening is the same, but for distributing the received data, it relies on `SendKeys` and sends keys on the fly and each window which has focus receives keys.

Comment: @Dinny Let me know the result :)

Comment: I've got a barcode scanner working here using SignalR, but i'm using it as a regular keyboard.  Works great.

Comment: @Amy - Sounds interesting. Let me give that a try as well. Thanks for the tip :)